# Fedora can't start anymore

Tags: linux, fedora

I've been trying to start my laptop for the last few days, and it just won't launch. The Fedora logo just stays on the screen without moving on. I hit F12, and I saw that Fedora failed to : start Gnome Display Manager, start D-bus System Message Bus, start Network Manager.

Would anyone know how I could fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open a TTY, login and run updates.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Alt+F2, can you login to the virtual terminal? If you can login, use `systemctl status gdm` and `dmesg` to check what happened.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have no idea what is a TTY, how do you open one ? I cannot login to the virtual terminal. The only terminal I can open is by pressing "c" when it asks me to choose between the fedora versions

Comment: Can you run any of the above commands in that terminal?

Comment: No I can't, the commands aren't recognized

Comment: The terminal just says grub> at the beggining of each line, if it is of any help.

Comment: No help at all, as this is grub you are entering and not Fedora. See the procedures the apply here from [Chapter 19. Basic System Recovery](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html).